# Why is php symfony framework method not used (controller)?

Tags: php, symfony

Any ideas what can be wrong? PHP Storm says, that homepage is unused. On webside there is still symfony homepage so it doesnt work even on site.

routes.yaml

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\QuestionController::homepage
```

QuestionController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class QuestionController
{
    public function homepage()
    {
        return new Response('What a bewitching controller we have conjured!');
    }
}
```

Update:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
```

also doesnt work work homepage()

Comment: Please clarify.  Does navigating to / work?

Comment: What you show for routes.yaml is not properly formatted, is that how it is in your file (no indents)?

Comment: Indents are ok in file. I just had problem with formatting it on this site. @Cerad im not sure what do u mean by that. All i was checking was homepage. And it didnt change

Comment: It's a language barrier.  I cannot tell from your words if the route is working or not or indeed if anything is actually wrong.  Try this, run 'bin/console debug:router' and see of the index route shows up.

Answer (score 0):

in config/routes create file annotation.yaml

with such code:

```yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

that's all, enjoy :)